# How to use a custom metadata file on azure hdinsight spark cluster

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-hdinsight, azure-blob-storage

I have a use case of loading the data from a .dat file(stored in azure blob store) for while running jobs on Azure HDinsight spark cluster.
I went through [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-use-blob-storage#address-files-in-azure-storage) doc to load it, as following in python(pyspark):

```
file='wasb:///<container_name>/<path>/CITYIP.dat'
with open(file) as f:
    print f.read()
```

which throws `IOError: No such file or directory`. I feel, I am doing something wrong here.

Can somebody point me to right direction, for loading a file in azure HDinsight spark cluster using pyspark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read the file and load in spark make sure the `hadoop-azure` dependency is added `"org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-azure" % "2.7.3"`

Then define the file system to be used in the underlying Hadoop configurations.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("read azure storage").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.azure", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.azure.account.key.yourAccount.blob.core.windows.net", "yourKey ")

val baseDir = "wasb[s]://BlobStorageContainer@yourUser.blob.core.windows.net/"
```

Now read the text file as

```
val file = spark.read.textFile(baseDir + "pathToTextFile")
```

**Note:** The code above is in scala hope you can change in `pyspark`

[Here](https://sktechie.wordpress.com/2018/02/12/how-to-data-from-azure-blob-storage-with-apache-spark/) is the full program that I tested